# Connecting to AWS Elasticsearch Service using R - Getting 404 Error

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I am trying to query AWS ElasticSearch Service (AWS ES) through a package in R called [`elastic`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elastic/elastic.pdf). I am getting an error when trying to connect to the server.

Here is an example:

```
install.packages("elastic")
library(elastic)
aws_endpoint = "<secret>"
   # I am certain the endpoint exists and is correct, as it functions with Kibana
aws_port = 80    
   # I have tried 9200, 9300, and 443 with no success

connect(es_host = aws_endpoint, 
    es_port = 80,
    errors = "complete")
ping()
Search(index = "foobar", size = 1)$hits$hits
```

Whether pinging the server, or actually trying to search a document, both retrieve this error:

```
Error: 404 - no such index
ES stack trace:
  type: index_not_found_exception
  reason: no such index
  resource.type: index_or_alias
  resource.id: us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
  index: us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com
```

I have gone into my AWS ES dashboard and made certain I am using indexes that exist. Why this error?

I imagine I am misunderstanding something about transport protocols. `elastic` interacts with elasticsearch's HTTP API. I thought this was fine.

How do I establish an approriate connection between R and AWS ES?

`R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)`; `elastic_0.7.8`

Comment: AWS's version of hosted Elasticsearch requires all requests to be signed (reference http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html). I don't see any obvious references that the ropensci/elastic package supports this signature scheme. I'm not aware of any CRAN packages that do this at the moment.

Comment: Thanks @DavidF.Severski. I'll look into this.

Comment: Actually, our server admin says we have not yet secured the ES url yet, so signing is not required. Any other thoughts? @DavidF.Severski

Answer (score 2):

Solved it.

**`es_path` must be specified as an empty string (`""`)**. Otherwise, `connect()` understands the AWS region (i.e. `us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com`) as the path. I imagine `connect()` adds the misunderstood path in the HTTP request, [following the format shown here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_talking_to_elasticsearch.html#_restful_api_with_json_over_http).

```
connect(es_host = aws_endpoint, 
   es_port = 80,
   errors = "complete",
   es_path = "" 
)
```

Just to be clear, the parameters I actually used is shown below, but they should not make a difference. **Fixing `es_path` is the key**.

```
connect(es_host = aws_endpoint, 
    es_port = 443, 
    es_path = "", 
    es_transport_schema  = "https")
```

Comment: Could you provide an example how aws_endpoint looks like? I'm struggling to find out myself. Thanks in advance!